# XCode 9 communicates with mysql but sends "nil" result

Tags: ios, mysql, database, xcode, null

This is my first time asking a question here, I'll try to be as concise as i can.

I have an application that is supposed to retrieve data from a MySQL database, that I actually have on a local server, using mmap and PHPMyAdmin.

I followed this tutorial: https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

The web service works fine, since it displays the right information encoded in JSON when I open it with the localhost.

I then managed to use the tutorial and to make it fit my needs, and I tried to display the data twice, with different results:

[image: My code that displays it]

[image: What I get as a result]

As you can see, the first textview where I try to display directly `feedItems[Indexpath.row]` displays the values of my database, but everything is equal to "nil"

The second line, supposed to just delay the data contained in the `mail` attribute of the client doesn't display anything.

The number of rows are correct (if I have 3 items in my table from the database, it will display 3 cells, if I have 4 it will display 4 etc...), and when I test that the data is downloaded in the code with a `print("Data downloaded")`, it indeed works.

So, what could it be? The webservice works and I can obviously connect my app to it, it just won't take the right values and put `nil` instead.

I'm not trying to fetch EVERY attribute of the table in the database (it has 10 attributes but I need just 6 of them for my app), and one of them is an integer that I tried to transform in a String before getting it, maybe the problem comes from that?

**EDIT**
I managed to display some of the data by not testing if it was equal  to nil or not. The problem was (and still is) that I  cannot get the "Bigint" value of my table, but I can get  the "text" values. 
In an answer the guy of the tutorial gave to a comment, he said that integer were parsed differently that texts, but he didn't explain how to overcome this problem.
So, the question is:
**How can I get my integer values in my table to be displayed in the app?**

Here's my web service (php file)

```
  <?php

    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","BATO");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM client";

    // Check if there are results
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
        // to hold the data
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        // Loop through each row in the result set
        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            // Add each row into our results array
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }


// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm then using a "homemodel"   class to retrieve the data, just as he does in the tutorial

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate{

    //properties

    weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!

    var data = Data()

    let urlPath: String = "http://localhost:8888/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

    func downloadItems() {

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Data downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }


    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let clients = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let client = ClientModel()



                client.IDClient = jsonElement["IDClient"] as? Int
            client.nom = jsonElement["Nom"] as? String
                client.addresse = jsonElement["Adresse"] as? String
                client.Numtel = jsonElement["NumTel"] as? String
                client.Mail = jsonElement["Mail"] as? String
                client.CPClient = jsonElement["CPClient"] as? String

           // }

            clients.add(client)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: clients)

        })
    }


}
```

And finally I get the data in the tableview controller

```
import UIKit

class SAV: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol{


    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedClient : ClientModel = ClientModel()

    @IBOutlet weak var SAVTableView: UITableView!
    let ClientTable = [ "Jean", "seb", "max", "jcp", "loutre" ,"Guillaume" , "Luc"]
    let DevisTable = [ 0.7, 7.7, 8.8, 3, 5, 10, 12]
    let ChantierTable = [ "Chantier 1", "Chantier 2", "Chantier 3", "Chantier 4", "Chantier 5","Chantier 6", ""]
    let AdresseTable = [ "7 rue mathis", "1 rue des Maris", "5 rue de la Gare", "9 rue des Perdrix", "12 rue des Faux","", ""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

         self.SAVTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40;
        self.SAVTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

        SAVTableView.delegate = self
        SAVTableView.dataSource = self

        let homeModel = HomeModel()
        homeModel.delegate = self
        homeModel.downloadItems()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.SAVTableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return feedItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let SAVCell = SAVTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chantiercell") as! SAVTableViewCell

        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: ClientModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! ClientModel

       // SAVCell.Clientlbl.text = "\(feedItems[indexPath.row])"
        SAVCell.Devislbl.text = " \(item.IDClient as Optional )"
        SAVCell.Chantierlbl.text = item.Mail



        return SAVCell
    }

    func alert(_ title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

If you know what I should do to be able to get the integer value of my table "IDClient", or have any other tutorial I cold follow, then please go ahead and let me know ! thanks !

Comment: Please edit your question, paste the code into it, and format it. And also remove the external links to pictures of code. Consider that people need to copy and paste your code to test their answer.

Comment: u have to show more of your code

Comment: It's done ! I just need to get integer (not only text, like the tutorial shows) from my database, in order to display them in the app. I just have no idea what to do :(